# Element not picking up values from an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that copies data from specific columns into another sheet, and I was trying to use an array to get the column names since they could be subject to change in the future. For some reason, when stepping through the loop to fill the array I can see that the values are being loaded in correctly, but when I get to the For Each loop, element is always empty. I feel like there's a simple fix but I just can't see it.

I've tried moving things around and declaring element as a variant, but the same process works just fine in another macro so I'm stumped.

```
Dim rows As Integer
Dim OneZeroCol As Integer
Dim FromCol As Integer
Dim ToCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ADcols As Integer
Dim el As Integer
Dim element As Variant

Dim colArray() As String

el = AD.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
OneZeroCol = AD.Cells.Find(What:="1/0", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
rows = (TD.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)

ReDim colArray(el)

'load values into array
For i = 1 To OneZeroCol - 1
    colArray(i) = AD.Cells(1, i).Value
Next i

'ERROR: ELEMENT COMING THROUGH EMPTY?? VALUE LOAD IS SUCCESSFUL BUT FAILS IN LOOP 18-10-19

'loop to copy data
For Each element In colArray
    FromCol = TD.Range("1:1").Find(element, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    ToCol = AD.Range("1:1").Find(element, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column

    For i = 2 To rows

        AD.Cells(i, ToCol).Value = TD.Cells(i, FromCol).Value

    Next i
Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: Couple notes off the bat: Use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Then, normally you want to check if the `Find` was successful before attempting to check the `Column` or `Row` of the found cell. Also, not sure why you `Redim` using `el` but then loop to `OneZeroCol - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm still relatively new to macro writing so it is appreciated. How do you check if Find was successful?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328395/using-the-find-function-in-vba). Basically you test if the result of `Find` isn't nothing, e.g. `If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then` in the answer.

Comment: `ReDim colArray(el)` will dimension the array `0 to el` and then the first iteration of `For Each ...` will return `colArray(0)` which will be `Empty`.  Always better to be explicit with array bounds `ReDim colArray(1 To el)`  (side note for the pedantic: you can override default bounds with Option Base 1, but imho better to just include the lower bound in the Dim)